# Adding perl to a webpage?

Tags: perl

I had posted a question before about asking how to use CGI perl to create webpages with perl.

The general idea I got was no one uses CGI with perl anymore.

So I am sorta stuck then, I would like to use perl with small website I want to create, some like a WebGUI. But I don't need anything really complex to start with, one suggestion was some thing called `catalyst` but that seems to be way more than I need.

Where can I go from here?

I have looked around and I seemed to be getting old pages nothing that really gives me any clear understanding of what is the easiest way to integrate perl with a website.

Comment: By the way Perl CGI is still used in websites and things like Moveable Type for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of Perl web frameworks. You could try also [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/).
It has no dependencies besides Perl core modules but offers a lot of functionalities.
At the same time it allows you to start with minimum knowledge about Perl.

```
  use Mojolicious::Lite;
  get '/' => {text => 'Hello World!'};
  app->start;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a quick start-up and easy simple cases, try [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/). I find it super easy to get something lightweight. Specifically, take a look at the [introduction](http://p3rl.org/Dancer%3a%3aIntroduction). That should be straightforward enough to build from.

Comment: Ok so I use Dancer inconjuction with HTML, CSS, etc.? Or is it standalone?

Comment: generally, you would put your html into templates: [templates in the intro](http://search.cpan.org/~xsawyerx/Dancer-1.3092/lib/Dancer/Introduction.pod#USING_TEMPLATES). there are also modules which will generate html for you. basically, you can do whatever you want to do; you just have to learn about how.

Comment: Also, you should note that if you _really_ do want to deploy your work under CGI, Dancer makes this easy as well: https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer::Deployment#Running-as-a-cgi-script-or-fast-cgi-

Answer (score -2):

If you want to learn basics of CGI/with Perl just learn regular Perl and remember that you have to output the HTTP header like so:

```
print 'Content-type: text/plain;';
print 'charset=iso-8859-1\n\n';
```

Then just print the rest of your HTML with print statements.

Keep in mind that the header data is on one line followed by two newlines; otherwise it will generate a 500-server-error due to the bad header.

Comment: If you're going to use CGI with Perl (and as the question says, few people do that any more) then using CGI.pm to do things like displaying the header wil make your life easier.

Comment: @davorg I said "the basics" that's pretty much as basic as you get. Besides you learn how the headers are actually formatted with CGI, in case you want to apply the knowledge to other languages, this way you're not depending on a Perl-specific module.

Comment: The reason few people use [CGI](http://p3rl.org/CGI) is that it is a terrible way to write a website. If you are going to write it as a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script, go ahead and use [CGI](http://p3rl.org/CGI).